# Anaconda on machine but conda command not found

Tags: zsh, terminal.app, anaconda, iterm2

I haven't used Anaconda in a while, I typed `conda info` into iTerm2 to read this error:

`zsh: command not found: conda`
I have copied the relevant `.bashrc` file information into the `.zshrc` file and still the issue continues.
I fear that the old install files are all in the wrong places and I have been unable to download a new copy.
Does anyone have any clues? I have run out of things to try...

The result from echo $PATH is this:

```
/anaconda/bin:/Users/cassy/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Users/cassy/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/anaconda3/bin:/Users/username/miniconda3/bin:/Users/cassy/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

Comment: Do you see the location of the `conda` binary in `echo $PATH`?

Comment: Thanks Nasir, yes it appears I have multiple Anaconda versions. The result from `echo $PATH` is this: `/anaconda/bin:/Users/cassy/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Users/cassy/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/anaconda3/bin:/Users/username/miniconda3/bin:/Users/cassy/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin`

Comment: Is there a `conda` binary in any of the anaconda directories such as `/anaconda/bin` or `/Users/cassy/anaconda/bin`? Do you have read and execute permissions to them?